# AWS appsync GraphQL aggregate counts

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Instead of all the items in return I want the number of items only in appsync query.Look at the below example:

**My schema :**

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  post: Post @belongsTo
}
```

Here in getPost query we can get all the comments list related to post if we won't provide pagination limit. But I don't want the list of comments, I want the total number of comments. When user will click on the comment icon I will fetch comments in separate query.

**Now my question is how to get that comments is there any in-built method avaliable or I have to do it manually (`how`)?**

Comment: All the default queries/mutations are listed on the appsync console. I don't think the count query is present so you have to do manually. For manually you can just query for the id of the comments and take a count of the array

Comment: Let say a post has 5 million comments if you retrive them all and count the latency will be very high.

Comment: Then you have to write your custom resolver with VTL, you can follow the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't have a `count` function in the API, and therefore, it is also not available in the VTL of AppSync. The concept of DynamoDB is to have scalable LOOKUP queries that are hitting a small number of records, and if you need to SCAN many records, it is possible however, not efficient.

The best way to achieve the counters you are after is to prepare them for a LOOKUP. On every `addComment` event, you can increase the comment counter, and on every `deleteComment` event, you can decrease that counter.

Here is an example of the [CLI command to increase a counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement), which you can include in your [resolver VTL code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-updateitem).

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name Posts \
    --key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
    --update-expression "ADD CommentCounter :q" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":q": {"N": "1"}}' \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: Yeah got you. But ```{"N":  1 }```.